# prepare Active Directory for exchange 2010

Tags: active-directory, exchange-2010, windows-server-2012, exchange

I am installing "Exchange Server 2010" on a "windows server 2012" system. As exchange installation prerequisites we have to prepare "Active Directory" but I already installed a Active Directory in other system. So my question is can use my existing Active Directory for exchange installation? if yes , how?

I am new to exchange server installation....

Comment: Please don't tell me that you only have a single domain controller for your AD where you're building Exchange.

Comment: The Exchange Server installation will run the necessary Ad prep for you. There's no need to run it manually. The Exchange server needs to be a member of the AD domain into which you want to install Exchange.

Comment: I have not prepare the AD yet for Exchange but I already installed AD another windows server.
do need to relate that installed AD with this exchange or i have prepare AD separately for exchange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use your existing AD infraestructure. The exchange installation is going to require an additional step in the DC:

Launch an elevated command prompt and run the following command:

D:\setup /PrepareAD

(asuming that you have the Exchange installation CD in D:)

Comment: I have not prepare the AD yet for Exchange but I already installed AD another windows server.
do need to relate that installed AD with this exchange or i have prepare AD separately for exchange?

Comment: No, you don't need a new AD, use the existing one.

Answer (score 1):

*I know someone else is going to say this, so I'll say it first: it sounds like you are in over your head. Hire a professional to set this up for you. This is one of the simplest prerequisites for setting up Exchange, and it only gets more complicated from here.*

To answer your question, Exchange needs to update the existing Active Directory schema with its own metadata and information in order for Exchange to work. So no, you do not need a separate AD infrastructure.

Comment: I had begun my own answer with "Where to start ...." Nice concise response.

Comment: I have not prepare the AD yet for Exchange but I already installed AD another windows server.
do need relate that installed AD with this exchange or i have prepare AD separately for exchange?

Comment: The existing AD. Please slow down and read the answers, and Microsoft's own documentation. It's very explicit.